# Calculate Appointments beetween two dates

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysqli

Situation:

I have arrays with information of the used appointments and the calculated days for the new appointment series based on PHP.

For example, the exist appointment array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2019-05-02
            [time_start] => 14:00:00
            [time_end] => 15:30:00
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2019-05-06
            [time_start] => 14:00:00
            [time_end] => 15:30:00
        )
)
```

Now, i will check have the calculated series (same array format) collisions with the exist appointments.

My Question:
How can i check if a collision exist beetween the start and end time and if yes how i can give the array a new value with a time windows after or before the exist appointment. This within a time windows from 08:00 am to 4:00 pm.

What i have is the calculation of the appointment days.

```
 private function calculate_dates($data, $measure)
{

    $this->load->model('calendar/calendar_model');
    $holiday_dates = $this->calendar_model->get_holidays();

    foreach ($holiday_dates as $key => $value) {
        $holidays[] = $value['holiday_date'];
    }

    $begin = new DateTime($data->measure_begin);
    $end = new DateTime($data->measure_end);
    $oneday = new DateInterval("P1D");
    $days = json_decode($data->measure_dates);
    $wdays = array();
    $ue_minutes = 0;

    $minutes = ($data->measure_ue * $measure->ue_minutes/2);
    $daterange = new DatePeriod( $begin, DateInterval::createFromDateString('+1 weekdays') ,$end );

    foreach(new DatePeriod($begin, $oneday, $end->add($oneday)) as $day) {
        $day_num = $day->format("N"); /* 'N' number days 1 (mon) to 7 (sun) */
        if($day_num < 6 ) { /* weekday */
            $wdays[] = $day;
        }
    }

    $count = 1;
    foreach($wdays as $date){
        foreach ($days as $key => $value) {
            if(mb_strtolower($date->format('l')) == $value){

                if(($data->measure_ue/2)+1 != $count){
                    if(in_array($date->format('Y-m-d'), $holidays)) {
                        $dates[] = $this->close_days($date, $days, true)->format('l, d.m.Y');
                    } else {
                        $dates[] = $date->format('l, d.m.Y');
                    }
                    $count++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return array(
        'dates' => $dates,
        'minutes' => round($minutes/count($dates))
    );
}

private function close_days($date, $days, $init = false)
{
    if($init){
        $days[] = 'saturday';
        $days[] = 'sunday';
    }

    if( in_array(mb_strtolower($date->format('l')), $days) ) {
        $this->close_days($date->modify('next day'), $days);
    }
    return $date;
}
```

Any Ideas for a solution or maybe a code for a better way?

Comment: You don't have an end date? What if it's a longer event/appointment?

Comment: I have a start date and the end date. The example calculates only the dates for the next free appointment. On the example array is the 01.05.2019 a holiday, so the calculation used the next day (02.05.2019).

It´s defined on $data->measure_begin and $data->measure_end.